# whats new in C# 4 for a static-typed guy

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

first of all let me say that I know about dynamic, no PIA, named and optional parameters and finally covariance and contravariance.

In my projects 99% of the time my code is in C#, I almost never do Office automation, I don't plan to use any dynamic language any time soon, and, besides being necessary for Office automation, I think named and optional parameters are wrong (and no, overloads do not count, if you have that many overloads the problem is in the design, not the language).

So whats there for a C# guy in a static-typed world?, The only thing appears to be covariance and contravariance, which sounds great, but I was hoping something more. The only bits that I'm excited to try are the parallel extensions for Linq but that's about it (and that's [available for 3.5 [as a CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en)).

Why are you exited about C# 4?

Comment: It seems to me this should be a Community Wiki.

Comment: C# 4.0 was a deliberately small release as far as new language features go. Feedback we get all the time is "please stop adding crazy new features; spend some time making what you've got work well with everything else you're putting out!"  So that's what we did. All the new C# 4.0 features focus on making dynamic languages, static languages and legacy object models/interfaces work together more smoothly. Making interoperability smoother is not exciting so it is unsurprising that you're not excited about it. Our aim is to produce _useful tools_, and useful is not always thrilling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing to be excited about in C# 4 from a non-COM, non-dynamic standpoint are covariance and contravariance.  Everything else is centered around dynamic typing.

Comment: "dynamic programming?" Dynamic typing seems to be a better word as dynamic programming is mostly associated with the problem solving strategy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: Optional parameters and named arguments aren't about dynamic typing.

Answer (score 12):

1. Better Garbage Collection
2. New Thread Pooling Engine
3. Code Contracts
4. If you're not doing ASP.NET WebForms development you wouldn't care, but, there are significant improvements there as well.

[Learning Resources for .NET 4.0 New Features](http://bogdanbrinzarea.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/learning-net-40-new-features/)

...hit the link for some good resources about some of the new features.

Comment: +1 for Code Contracts (not a language feature per se, but close enough)

Comment: Hmm... those are all very cool things but none of them are language features.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because you bring some important points, but selected Andrew's answer because the question was for C# 4 features

Answer (score 5):

Really optional default parameters, co/contravariance (*has been* an advantage of Java) and the ParallelFX.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new chart control now in the toolbox... yea I got nothin else..