# Is there a concise list of .NET 3.0 to 4.0 BCL deltas?

Tags: .net

Does anybody know of or have a detailed list of how the BCL in .NET 4.0 has changed from 3.0?  In other words, what types have been added or deprecated (or how have they changed)?

All I have been able to find is the list of new features, such as the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Features_of_C.23_4.0), any of the endless MSDN blogs entries about it, or some questions here on SO ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888893/whats-new-in-c-4-for-a-static-typed-guy), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237041/confirmed-features-of-net-4-0)).  Knowing about those is important, but I am also interested in what new types we have to use.

Taking a gander using VS2010 Beta 1, I noticed a few new ones that looked interesting and fun:

1. [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx)
2. [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(VS.100).aspx)
3. The whole [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(VS.100).aspx) namespace.
4. Additions to Threading such as [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parallel(VS.100).aspx) types and [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(VS.100).aspx) namespace
5. [Charting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting(VS.100).aspx) namespace
6. Etc...

I know that it is still in beta and things could change, but I think it's worth trying to get a leg up on learning about all the new classes now (not just the hyped-up ones).

I don't really feel like writing my own reflect-and-diff tool to generate this list, so I'm hoping the list (or the tool to generate it) already exists.

By the way, I already checked [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)'s [add-ins](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins) and the [Diff](http://www.codingsanity.com/diff.htm) one (while being great) doesn't feel quite right.  I think it would be great for getting down to the dirty details, but seems like overkill for just getting the list of the high-level deltas.

EDIT:

Using bdukes answer, I have created a Google Docs [spreadsheet](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=rpsf2ykPRSB2lFloARfLPuw) that lists all the new types in 4.0 as of Beta 1.  It also contains links to the MSDN online documentation (or a Google Search for generic types since their URI is not as easy to autogenerate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt there's a nice compiled list out there yet (it is still a beta, as you say).

You may want to check out NDepend for a more controlled diff experience (see [Patrick's post on some of the changes](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/05/21/a-quick-analyze-of-the-net-fx-v4-0-beta1.aspx)).

**UPDATE**: The BCL Team just released [a blog post about what's new from them](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/05/22/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-1-justin-van-patten.aspx).  This includes:

- Code Contracts
- Parallel Extensions
- `BigInteger`
- Co- & Contra-Variance
- Tuples
- `SortedSet<T>` & `ISet<T>`
- File System Enumeration Improvements
- `MemoryMappedFiles`
- Registry Improvements
- Globalization data updated to Unicode 5.1
- `ResourceManager` Improvements
- Compression Improvements

Comment: Looking through his results, I wished he had added an order-by to his queries. Still, almost exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on MSDN that (although not really a concise list of deltas) does go through what is new and has pointers to more reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409230(VS.100).aspx ([direct link to the BCL section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409230(VS.100).aspx#base_class_libraries))